# Memory Limit Exceed error in python

Tags: python

```
sum=0
n=int(input())
x = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
for i in range(n):
    str1=str(2**x[i])
    if(len(str1)>2):
        str1[len(str1)-2 :]
    else:
        str1
    sum+=int(str1)
print(sum%100)
```

Input

3

1 2 3

Output

14

```
Constraints
 1<=n<=10^7
 0<=x<=10^18
```

This code is working  fine for small values,like n=4 & x=8,7,6,4 and output is=64.but not for the given constraints.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your actual question?

Comment: pls review once again.....i have updated the question

Comment: @ashutoshpratapsingh could you elaborate what exactly you want to achieve with this code?

Comment: the question is given in coding contest . Basic test cases(which i have mentioned above) are passed but after submission it shows memory limit exceeded .

Answer (score 0):

Well... since you do

```
2**x[i]
```

which results in an integer value, that will most definately fail when x get's large enough.

You can do the math:

Assuming your computer has 8GB of main memory, that would be `8*8*1024^3=68719476736` bits of memory. So the single largest value that would span your **entire**(not possible to get this large, but I just want to highlight what the physical limit is here) memory, would be `2**68719476736` which lies somewhere between `2^(10^10)` to `2^(10^11)`

So as it stands, I think your code cannot work for numbers this large.